# Serial downvoted by a moderator

Tags: support, questions, moderators, down-votes, serial-voting

I got serial downvoted by a mod ([Rubén Rivera](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n?tab=profile)) a few hours ago:

[image]

The questions were viciously chosen so that they will be removed by the Stack Exchange automated removal question script (a.k.a. Roomba).

Why the serial downvotes and how can I appeal it?

---

Links to the questions: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/18147/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201121095038/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/18147/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation)).

Comment: I am wondering how would one know who upvotes or downvotes!

Comment: @SeverusSnape as for me I am still wondering why a moderator would serial downvote perfectly fine questions. Many mysteries on stack exchange.

Comment: How do you know Ruben downvoted? AFAIK, we can't see who downvotes or upvotes. Before he wrote the answer here, there was no way you could know it.

Answer (score 2):

The votes that you are referring aren't "serial downvoting" b/c the referred questions didn't include any research effort, they were very short (meaning unclear / brevivity should not sacrifice clarity), and they were not viciously choosen.

In new  tab of the main site Questions page I found a bad question, as the OP is a >10k rep user before taking any action I took a look to the OP profil. I found that they have several 0 votes questions, these questions are of the same "style" (no research effort, very short). Then I reviewed one by one all the OP questions that had 0 votes, 0 answers and very low number of views (38 questions). I choose to downvote only the oldest b/c they deserve be downvoted and b/c they were abandoned questions.

It's worthy to note that two of the downvoted are five and three years old and that when they were downvoted have not been edited and hadn't any answer.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/136776/revisions
[image]

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/136637/revisions
[image]

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/109782/revisions
[image]

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/86482/revisions
[image]

Today a couple of them were edited and all were self answered.

Regarding the way to "appeal" the downvotes,  there isn't a way to "appeal" downvotes b/c they aren't ♦ moderation actions, but you can invite me to chat, or as you already did, post here in meta. I reserve for my self the right to answer / abandone unpolite posts/conversations.

Reference

- [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/289691)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.1) This was serial downvoting: you targeted me and serially downvoted my questions. 2) All the questions you downvoted were clear. If you disagree, then you should leave a comment to ask for clarification. 3) If you downvote questions that don't show any research, then you have to downvote the vast majority of questions posted here. 4) The fact that the question was posted a while ago isn't a reason to downvote them.

Comment: We need to vote more.

Comment: I wonder: as a moderator, why downvote them just to push them toward automatic deletion? Why not just delete them on your own?

Comment: @Rubén yes but for the right reasons.

Comment: @gparyani The deletion done by a mod occurs inmediately and AFAIK this will not notify the OP that their questions were deleted. By the other hand the questions aren't spam or blatantly off-topic.