# Is this site dead?

Tags: support

I've asked 3 questions and received maybe a dozen views total. No votes, no answers, no downvote pile-on, nothing.

Is this site dead? If so, where can I ask questions about using Facebook?

Comment: It's not dead but certainly we need more regulars. Sidenote : I use Facebook very rarely.

Comment: Most of the recent [tag:facebook*] questions have the same situation as yours but between them there is one from October that has >2k views and two answers.

Comment: I suspect it is more the case that Facebook is dead, not this site.

Comment: @Chenmunka It does have less than 3 billion users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this site dead?

Mostly yes. In my experience, most questions get no upvotes, no answers, and only a couple of views. As a result many questions get automatically removed (that's what happens with questions with score 0 and no answer). At least you can be happy that your questions didn't get downvoted or close voted for no valid reason ([example 1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4777/18147) ; [example 2](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4775/18147)). Downvotes and close votes seem to be the main activity going on here nowadays, which doesn't help motivate people to contribute to this website. You can see on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year that only 10 users received over 1k reputation points this year, which shows that the website has almost no activity.

The following table shows that the median number of views on a question here is only 42 after 12 months ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357162/178179), 25%, 50% and 75 are percentiles):

[image]

> If so, where can I ask questions about using Facebook?

You can post your questions on https://www.reddit.com/r/facebook/ and https://www.quora.com/.

Answer (score 1):

This site is not dead but certainly [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) hasn't the same activity as other tags.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/topusers show that in the last 30 days there aren't top answerers and either top askers in contrary to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/google-sheets/topusers that shows that in the las 30 days there are top answerers and top askers.

Please consider to help to "revive" [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) by answering some recent questions or suggesting meaningful edits to make them better and intereresting for Facebook experts.